# Tornado Framework (FacebookGraphMixin)

Tags: python, facebook, request, send, tornado

I wanted to try sending App request from my Facebook app to a user using Tornado Framework. I was following http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/auth.html but I have no idea how to resolve this error. Any professionals out there? Thanks!

Error Log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "send.py", line 33, in main
    test.get(app_access_token, player_id)
  File "send.py", line 15, in get
    callback=self.async_callback(self._on_post))
AttributeError: 'Send' object has no attribute 'async_callback'
```

Code

```
import tornado.auth
import tornado.escape
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
from tornado import httpclient

class Send(tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    def get(self, app_access_token, player_id):
        self.facebook_request(
            "/"+player_id+"/apprequests",
            post_args={"message": "I am an app request from my Tornado application!"},
            access_token=app_access_token,
            callback=self.async_callback(self._on_post))

    def _on_post(self, new_entry):
        if not new_entry:
            # Call failed; perhaps missing permission?
            self.authorize_redirect()
            return
        self.finish("Posted a message!")

def main():
    key = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    player_id = "100003395454290" #fake id
    http_client = httpclient.HTTPClient()
    response = http_client.fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="+key+"&client_secret="+secret+"&redirect_uri=&code=")
    app_access_token = response.body.replace("access_token=","")

    test = Send()
    test.get(app_access_token, player_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my answer does not directly answer the OP's question. But as this shows up in the top search results for the error `AttributeError: 'XxxxxHandler' object has no attribute 'async_callback'`

It is worth noting that starting Tornado v4.0 the `async_callback` function has been removed. To quote the [Backwards-compatibility notes](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v4.0.0.html?highlight=async_callback#backwards-compatibility-notes):

> The `RequestHandler.async_callback` and `WebSocketHandler.async_callback`
>   wrapper functions have been removed; they have been obsolete for a
>   long time due to stack contexts (and more recently coroutines).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to subclass `tornado.web.RequestHandler`. Change:

```
class Send(tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
```

To:

```
class Send(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
```

Comment: Hey thanks Rob!
But is there a way to do this without tornado.web.RequestHandler?

Comment: @yori, `async_callback` is a method of that `tornado.web.RequestHandler` so you would have to find a way to do it without using that method.

Comment: Just wondering... Do you think its possible without using tornado.web.RequestHandler? My boss said to not use tornado.web.RequestHandler :( I am a bit lost why.

Comment: @yori, there is your boss problem! You cannot use `tornado.web.RequestHandler` methods, without inheritance from them. =)