# Facebook apprequest

Tags: python, facebook, request, tornado

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tornado Framework (FacebookGraphMixin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009406/tornado-framework-facebookgraphmixin)

I am trying to build an apprequest using Tornado Framework. Problem is that I am not allowed to use tornado.web.RequestHandler. Which means I cannot use async_callback() function. Is there way to get around that might work? Thanks.

First: (with tornado.web.RequestHandler)

```
class mainH(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    def get(self):
        self.facebook_request(
            "/"+player_id+"/apprequests",
            post_args={"message": "I am an app request!"},
            access_token=app_access_token,
            callback=self.async_callback(self._on_post))
```

Second: (removed tornado.web.RequestHandler)

```
class mainH(tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    def get(self):
        self.facebook_request(
            "/"+player_id+"/apprequests",
            post_args={"message": "I am an app request!"},
            access_token=app_access_token,
            callback=self.async_callback(self._on_post)) # can't use this line!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `tornado.web.RequestHandler`, then you're not going to be able to use libraries that require it, such as `tornado.auth`. "Not allowed" is a bit strange; I'd challenge that requirement.